# Is there a way to authenticate both Gmail Oauth and Google Contacts API AuthSub at one time?

Tags: api, oauth, gmail, contacts

I can access a users gmail account using oauth, and i can access a users contacts and their contact groups through google contacts API (which uses AuthSub). For my application i need both of these, is there a way i can authenticate both at once, so that i don't require users to go through two separate authentication sessions?

Or is there a way i can get access to a user's contact groups using the Gmail oAuth alone?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its possible because it seems like authsub is a different process and would need to be handled separately. However, i recommend getting both authenticated at once using oauth by specifying the "scope" parameter of the request to include both the contacts url and the gmail one.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar question - sorry for bringing up an old thread.

@benjaminlotan - you said "However, i recommend getting both authenticated at once using oauth by specifying the "scope" parameter of the request to include both the contacts url and the gmail one."

How exactly does one do that?

Current code is:

```
// Prepare the OAuth extension
string scope = GoogleConsumer.GetScopeUri(GoogleConsumer.Applications.Contacts);
Global.GoogleWebConsumer.AttachAuthorizationRequest(authReq, scope);
```

You can only specify one scope, and I can't seem to find a way to concatenate the URIs so that that I can also add GoogleConsumer.Applications.Gmail to the scope.

Comment: sorry, figured it out, they just get concatenated by a space.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick python example (you didn't write what language your were using), hope it helps!

```
def GetAuthSubUrl(next):
    oauthURL = urlparse(next)
    oauthURL = oauthURL.scheme + '://' + oauthURL.netloc + oauthURL.path + "oauth"
    scope = ['https://picasaweb.google.com/data/', 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/']
    secure = False
    session = True
    gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService()
    return gd_client.GenerateAuthSubURL(oauthURL, scope, secure, session);
```